# Regex match only one letter before and after pattern

Tags: regex

Im trying to find a regex that only matches any character in the beginning and any character after the pattern one time or no time. So `XpatternY` should match but also `pattern` alone should be a match. 
I tryied using `[A-Z]?pattern[A-Z]?` but this regex also recognizes `XXpatternYY` or anything else before and after pattern

Comment: Per rules in [tag:regex] tag, "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." In your case, the best tool is negative lookbehind and lookahead, but there are dialects lacking one or both of them (if I understood the question). Also, the question is ambiguous - would `"blahXpatternYblah"` match (as X and Y are not repeated)? or do you want at most one character before and after in the whole string?

Comment: Try `^[A-Z]?pattern[A-Z]?$`

Comment: Your regex does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

[`\b[A-Z]?pattern[A-Z]?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kDldCX/1)

Or use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the line:

[`^[A-Z]?pattern[A-Z]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/kDldCX/2)